# Can a planet dream of sheep?

Tags: creature-design, planets, intelligence

I had a peculiar dream...

There is a terrestrial planet orbiting an unknown multi stars system, that planet in fact is alive as in its a living planet. Just like the Portuguese man of war it is consists of a colony of multicellular organisms, it generates heat and a broad spectrum of radiowave and microwave.

There are also many fauna and flora inhabiting on the surface, all of them reacts to the radio wave and microwave emitted by the living planet.

To suggest that all of the fauna are the puppets and the planet is the puppeteer is inaccurate because the radiowave and microwave signals are completely random but at the same time all those surface dwellers do not have self awareness and they don't have memory. They are neither the imitation of life nor ghost in the shells, yet they are clearly capable of showing empathy and compassion. They can develop complex social behaviour and sometimes go to war against each other.

I am wondering could the noise in the form of electromagnetic wave helps create a flourishing civilization unconsciously like a dream actually transforming the landscape of reality?

Comment: Is that planet called Azathoth?

Comment: For those wondering why I omitted the word ”electric” in the title is because imagine they develops AI and it starts to probe who is it's creator... sorry should I go back to (more) sleep?

Comment: You might want to Google “Sid Meiers Alpha Centauri” - one of the victory conditions is ‘become one with a slumbering telepathic planet’.

Comment: you may want to read dark side of the sun by terry Pratchett which probably has the most realistic thinking planet, The First Sirian Bank

Answer (score 1):

Not in our current planets/life. There is no evolutionary benefit of tapping to the electromagnetic spectrum unless these have impact on the fauna.

However, if the physics of life can be altered, then everything could be possible. Crystals that grow with the electromagnetic waves could become "alive". They will have their own goals like reaching to that salt deposit to keep growing, but EM radiation will have impact on them too. They will fight when EM radiation is hectic, causing them have fractures that needs to be healed by scarce resources. They will be more content when there are harmonious melodies.

This kind of life will be slow. Movement will be measured in cm/hour. And wars will span centuries.

Comment: Isn't tapping to the electromagnetic spectrum exactly what photosynthetic organisms do?

Comment: That is visible light though. Visible light does not penetrate mantle.

Comment: @Cem Kalyoncu The mantle isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: I was thinking mantle will be the skin of the planet, thus the EM coming from the core will be blocked. I realized I didn't said that in the answer though.